# MATLAB : dynamic variables not updated directly in the workspace

Tags: matlab, variables, dynamic

I have a problem with some varaibles.
I create variables dynamically in a loop.

```
  for i=1:nbr
     assignin('base', ['x_',num2str(i)],0) 
  end
```

And after, I would like to put the result of my function in these variables. But the variables in the base of the workspace are not updated directly so I have an error "Undefined function or variable".  How can I fix my problem ?

```
for i=1:nbr 
      ['x_',num2str(i)]= fonction(input);
  end
```

Thank you in advance

Best regard

Comment: That's bad practice. Better use cell arrays

Comment: Really, you want cell arrays.  Each cell array element is itself a matrix, or any other kind of MATLAB variable.  So exactly the same as dynamic variable names, except readable and higher-performing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, use a cell array:

```
x{i} = function(input);
```

Then return the entire cell array back to the caller, so that you never need to use `assignin`.  The whole function body would look like this:

```
function x = myfunction(someinput)

for i=1:nbr
    x{i} = someotherfunction(input);
end
% Cell array x is returned from the function
```